# Looking for a use case of a $k$-$d$ tree with a norm other than $L^2$

Tags: data-structures, computational-geometry

In [Python's implementation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.query_ball_point.html) of [$k$-$d$ tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) 
it is possible to manually change the norm used for computing distances from
$L^2$ to [$L^p$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space).

When would one use a norm other than $L^2$ in a $k$-$d$ tree?

Answer (score 2):

For example, when you want to report all the points in distance $r$ from a query point under the $L_1$ norm, which is a natural case. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry.